# What's wrong with this line of wordpress PHP code? (from a tutorial)

Tags: php, wordpress

I know this is normally frowned upon, but I took this from a tutorial, so I am a little surprised as to why it isn't working.

Here is the impacted line of code:

```
$document_root = rtrim(str_replace(array('/', '\'), '/', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']), '/');
```

Error messages in apache's error log:

```
[Sun Jul 27 01:01:47 2014] [error] [client 24.62.230.8] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'DOCUMENT_ROOT' (T_STRING), expecting ')' in /home/folder/wp/wp-config.php on line 8
[Sun Jul 27 01:01:47 2014] [error] [client 24.62.230.8] PHP Stack trace:
[Sun Jul 27 01:01:47 2014] [error] [client 24.62.230.8] PHP   1. {main}() /home/folder/wp/index.php:0
[Sun Jul 27 01:01:47 2014] [error] [client 24.62.230.8] PHP   2. require() /home/folder/wp/index.php:3
[Sun Jul 27 01:01:47 2014] [error] [client 24.62.230.8] PHP   3. require_once() /home/folder/wp/wp-blog-header.php:12
```

Context: Here is the tutorial that I followed to achieve this. Check out wp-config.php - http://polycademy.com/blog/id/148/modern_wordpress_workflow_with_composer

Comment: \ escapes a character in a string. If you really want it to count as normal string use \\

Comment: It appears later in the tutorial they corrected themselves or something to do with the <code> block parsing

Comment: Figured it was something along those lines, but was also tired. Thanks guys

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this :

```
$document_root = rtrim(str_replace(array('/', '\\'), '/', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']), '/');
```